# Can't run my first project in AndroidStudio

Tags: android

I have just installed Android Studio in my windows 10 but the template project is not running in my emulator, Anyone knows how to solve it?

I used the default emulator(Nexus 5X API 28*86)

[This is the output and eventlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TQ6t.png)

[This is the exception with ADB , but some people online said just ignore it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aHbr.png)

[This is my SDK tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jetC1.png)

Comment: please add the relevant code as well. you get an invalid escape sequence in line 1. Where is that?

Comment: `code`package com.example.hellowrold;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}

Comment: I  didn't change anything of the empty project except the name.and the error line means i need to clean it.But after that , i still can not run it.

Answer (score -2):

If there is no error in your code i suggest to use Nox Player as  your emulator.
its free and you can find from here [download Nox player for PC](https://noxofficial.com/nox-for-pc/)
after installation dont run it! click on RUN button in android studio for getting start adp so execute Nox player and sfter starting it up you should press RUN button in android studio and there is awesome nox player in your emulator list.
select it and enjoy using it

Comment: please don't add a suggestion that doesn't necessarily provide a solution as an answer. This is what comments are there for.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo ok,i'm newbie in sof

Comment: no worries, that's why I left the comment. The downvote didn't come from me!